# Looping through my array returns error chars[i] as "undefined", though console.log(chars[i].index) display the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am looping through my dateIndex Array, but i get dateIndex[i] as undefined, but when i console.log the dateIndex[i].index, the value is displayed.

```
let dateIndex  =  {
  dateAndoutPutElements:[
    {"d_index": 3, "outPutElement": "1st"},
    {"d_index": 11, "outPutElement": "2nd"},
    {"d_index": 19, "outPutElement": "3rd"},
    {"d_index": 27, "outPutElement": "4th"},
    {"d_index": 35, "outPutElement": "5th"}
  ]
}; 

let chars = dateIndex.dateAndoutPutElements;
console.log(chars);
console.log("Index is " + chars[1].d_index);
let len=""; 
let day=1;                                                   
for (let i = 0; len = chars.length; i++) {
  console.log("Index is " + chars[i].d_index);   // Error occurs here apparently

  var date = data.list[chars[i].d_index].dt_txt;
  var tempValue = data.list[chars[i].d_index].main.temp;
  var descript = data.list[chars[i].d_index].weather[0].description;
  var icon = data.list[chars[i].d_index].weather[0].icon;

  console.log('Day:'+ day+ ' forecast');
  console.log(date);
  console.log(tempValue);
  console.log(descript);
  console.log(icon);
  console.log(chars[i].outPutElement);
  let ic = '<div> <img height="150" width="150" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+icon+'@2x.png" ></img></div>'; 

  day++;
  let output =         
    '<p> Date:         '+ date +  
    '<br>              '+ ic +  
    '<br>Temperature:  '+ Math.round(tempValue) +'&degC'   
    '<br>Description:  '+ descript +   '</p>';

  document.getElementById(chars[i].outPutElement).innerHTML = output;


  //View.show5DayForecast(date, ic, tempValue, descript, chars[i].outPutElement);   
}
```

**ERROR message:**

> TypeError: chars[i] is undefined
> fiveDaysForecastCityWeatherLoad_Copy http://127.0.0.1:5501/model/reserByra-model.js:129
> promise callback*fiveDaysForecastCityWeatherLoad_Cop

Comment: your for loop is incorrect, `len = chars.length` should be `i < chars.length`

Comment: `for (let i = 0; len = chars.length; i++) {` <--- your comparison is wrong.... it is always going to be true (unless chars is empty)

Comment: @George, i tried that before and it didn't work. I changed that now and tried, it works fine now foe some reason. Thanks alot. But then i  experience another problem, where the others elements (date,icon, and temp) are displayed, but not last one "descript" .

Comment: you didn't include `data` in your code snippet, so I can't help you with that
check that description exists in data

Comment: @George description exist in the data, and i've even console.log() it and it's shown, but doesn't appear in the screen though.   4th reserByra-model.js:141:25
Index is 35 reserByra-model.js:129:25
Day:5 forecast reserByra-model.js:136:25
2020-11-10 06:00:00 reserByra-model.js:137:25
15.24 reserByra-model.js:138:25
[clear sky] reserByra-model.js:139:25
01n